# Iterate over std::fs::ReadDir and get only filenames from paths

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out how to do a 'list Comprehension' with rust. I have a `ReadDir` iter that I want to map and only get the filenames of the paths. I'm thinking it would look something like:

```
// get current dir paths
let paths = fs::read_dir(&Path::new(
    &env::current_dir().unwrap())).unwrap();

// should contain only filenames
let files_names = paths.map(|&x| {
    match (*x).extensions() {
        Some(y) => y,
        None => //What do I do here? break?
};
```

I know my expression is likely horrendously broken, but is there a way to make this a single expression that I can bind `file_names` to?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll probably want to use `Path`'s `file_name()` method which yields the file name *if* it's a regular file, which is why it returns an `Option`.

I imagine you'd want to ignore the file names of things that aren't regular files, i.e. for which `file_name()` would return `None`, in which case you will probably want to leverage `Iterator`'s `filter_map` method which is basically like filter and map put together, i.e. you're able to map (in this case the path -> file name) and filter by returning the mapped result as an `Option`, where `None` would signify that you want to filter that value out.

The annoying thing will be that you have to check each item returned by the `ReadDir` iterator, since that's a `Result` type, so you'll have to see if it's `Ok`. If you just want to ignore non-`Ok` (i.e. `Err`) entries in the directory (e.g. entries for which you don't have permission), you can simply convert it to an `Option` using `Result`'s `ok()` method and integrate that in the `filter_map`.

You'll also have to attempt to create a `String` from the returned `file_name()`, since it may not necessarily be UTF-8. Files with non-UTF-8 names can simply be ignored (in this example) again using a combination of `map` and `and_then`.

Here's what it would look like if you make it ignore non-`Ok` directory entries and paths which aren't regular files (and thus return `None` on `file_name()`) as well as files whose file names are not UTF-8:

```
let paths = fs::read_dir(&Path::new(
  &env::current_dir().unwrap())).unwrap();

let names =
paths.filter_map(|entry| {
  entry.ok().and_then(|e|
    e.path().file_name()
    .and_then(|n| n.to_str().map(|s| String::from(s)))
  )
}).collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=822be00f142374cec364&version=stable)

If you're not very familiar with Rust's functional flow-control functions, e.g. `map`, `and_then`, etc. on `Result` and `Option`, then here's what it would look like expanded out, *without* ignoring errors and without doing error handling. I leave that up to you:

```
let paths = fs::read_dir(&Path::new(
  &env::current_dir().unwrap())).unwrap();

let names =
paths.map(|entry| {
  let entry = entry.unwrap();

  let entry_path = entry.path();

  let file_name = entry_path.file_name().unwrap();

  let file_name_as_str = file_name.to_str().unwrap();

  let file_name_as_string = String::from(file_name_as_str);

  file_name_as_string
}).collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1ff01269fa61a0ccf120&version=stable)