# How can I filter a list of filenames by their extension?

Tags: rust

I managed to read all files from one path to a `Vec`, and now I want to filter by extension.

```
let path = Path::new(r"C:\Testpath");
let mut faxvec: Vec<String> = Vec::new();

for element in path.read_dir().unwrap() {
    // if match element
    faxvec.push(element);
}
```

I want to only push the files to the vector that end with ".txt"

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE]?

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you load your code at the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) and [edit] your question to include a link. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question might be answered by the answers of [Iterate over std::fs::ReadDir and get only filenames from paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31225745/155423) and [Filtering files or directories discovered with fs::read_dir()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58062887/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Rust provides a [filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter). You can use it like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e7d10aa1720cb11ab7679fdf9c538a6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
fn main() {
    let mut faxvec: Vec<std::path::PathBuf> = Vec::new();
    for element in std::path::Path::new(r"C:\Testpath").read_dir().unwrap() {
        let path = element.unwrap().path();
        if let Some(extension) = path.extension() {
            if extension == "txt" {
                faxvec.push(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I feel this is a bit more idiomatic:

```
fn get_csv_paths(dir: &str) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let paths = std::fs::read_dir(dir)?
        // Filter out all those directory entries which couldn't be read
        .filter_map(|res| res.ok())
        // Map the directory entries to paths
        .map(|dir_entry| dir_entry.path())
        // Filter out all paths with extensions other than `csv`
        .filter_map(|path| {
            if path.extension().map_or(false, |ext| ext == "csv") {
                Some(path)
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    Ok(paths)
}
```

It will `Err` if something goes wrong reading the directory, but will otherwise get all paths that end with `csv`.